# Parsing JSON Data From MySQL Table to Different Divs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Having a jQuery Ajax request from MySQL database I know how to render the data in an HTML element format like tables or list as below:

```
$.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"appdata.php",
                success: function (newdata) {
                    $('#result').html(newdata);
                }
       });
```

The PHP as:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '******', '********');
$resultStr = '';
$query = 'SELECT * FROM appusers';
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $resultStr.='<ul>';
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
          $resultStr.= '<li>'.$row['fname'].' - '.$row['lname'].' - '.$row['phone'].'</li>';
        }
         $resultStr.= '</ul>';
        }
        else {
               $resultStr = 'Nothing Found';
             }
    }
echo $resultStr;
?>
```

The other option, also, is passing the result as JSON by using the `json_encode()` as below

```
   $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '******', '********');
   $query = 'SELECT * FROM appusers';
   $result = $mysqli->query($query)->fetch_array();
   echo json_encode($result);
```

Now I am totally confused how to use this `json_encode($result)` in the Ajax call?
For example can you please let me know if I want render the result of the query in series of divs like

```
<div id"fname"></div>
<div id"lname"></div>
<div id"phone"></div>
```

how can I parse this in ajax success property? and associuate each field on related div?
Thanks for you help in advanced.

update:

```
var varfname;
var varlname;
var varphone;

$(#fname).html(varfname);
$(#lname).html(varlname);
$(#phone).html(varphone);
```

Comment: in the above code you were showing the data as list . but you want in divs right?

Comment: Hi ashok_p yes but I need to use the second way as I may pass the result on some JavaScript variables to use them later on the page

Comment: for multiple rows do you want to give all three divs each time for every row? or the other way ?

Comment: This is exactly the way that I am confused! but for now lets just think to save only one row in some variables like varfname, varlname, varphone.

Comment: can you just show me how the sample html  data should look so that i can help. or just make a jsfiddle.

Comment: @ashok_p, can you please take a look at update at post? what I need to know is parsing the json to var varfname;var varlname;var varphone; varaiblaes.

Comment: if i use variable like that then every row will over write the previous row values

Comment: lets keep it simple and assume that we are getting only one row from the table please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this may help you, but depending on your requirement you have to change the `newdata`  variable value.
this still need some editing depending upon your requirement.

```
 $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"appdata.php",

                    success: function (data) {
                       var newdata='';

                        $.each(data, function(item,value) 
                        {

                          newdata+='<div id="'+item+'">'+value+'</div>';

                        });
                        $('#result').html(newdata);

                    }
           });
```